# CakePHP4 - Create Record with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm new working with CakePHP and I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to add a form that can post to a different db table with ajax. Basically, I've got a form that carries out a search which works fine, but before the user carries out the search I need to capture his email & some other fields and store them in a separate table in my db.

While I've been able to set up a form and send the data to the controller, I can't get past an error 400 / bad request. I'm not sure if it's because I've got the post url set up wrong (having enabled: $this->loadComponent('FormProtection');

Any help or orientation would be greatly appreciated!! I haven't been able to figure this out, maybe I'm approaching the problem wrong or I should use a post link (if that's even possible).

The setup that I've currently got:

```
index.php => website.com/app/services:

<div id="user_basics"> 
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Visitor') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('email');
        echo $this->Form->control('city');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

jQuery: 
$('#user_basics form').submit(function(event) {
    
var ajaxdata = $("#user_basics form").serializeArray();

event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?= $this->Url->build(["controller" => "visitors","action" => "addExternal"]); ?>",
        type:"POST",
        headers: $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val(),
        data:ajaxdata,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.error(response.message, response.title);
            console.log("nope");
        }
    });

});
```

I haven't included the controller file with the addExternal action.

Note: I'm pointing to visitor controller, I believe that's the right way to go about this - sending the users' data to the visitor controller which is already setup to connect to the db)

Comment: Have you checked your Cake logs to see if it's telling you something about the problem?

Comment: Just go the debug kit working and I'm learning to use it. I figured out a solution, though I feel it's missing something. It works, but not 100% sure it's done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple mistake

```
var ajaxdata = $("#user_basics form").serializeArray();
```

You are trying to Serialize array from a form which have"user_basics form".
Here id "user_basic" may have multiple form.
so it's best idea to create the form with id

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null,[
           'id'=>'user_basic_form',
    ]) ?>
```

```
var ajaxdata = $("#user_basic_form").serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

So working through the logs, I found that the csfr / formprotection can't be used simultaneously and there were probably some other errors along the way. Here's what working now, though I'm curious if it's the best route.

I have 2 tables, services & visitors. On the services index I need to be able to create a record in the visitors table (where I'll store users' email/data which allows them to carry out a search).

VisitorsController:

```
public function initialize(): void {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');   
        $this->loadComponent('FormProtection');
    }
    public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event){
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->FormProtection->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['userinfo']);
    }

    public function userinfo(){
        // $this->autoRender = false;
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->response = $this->response->withDisabledCache();
        }
        
        $visitor = $this->Visitors->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $visitor = $this->Visitors->patchEntity($visitor, $this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Visitors->save($visitor)) {}
        }
        $this->set(compact('visitor')); 
    }
```

Visitors Index:

```
<div id="user_basics"> 
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>

<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Visitor') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('email');
        echo $this->Form->control('city');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('ok')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    
    $('#user_basics form').submit(function(event){
        
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $('div.response');
        var csrf = $('input[name=_csrfToken]', $form).val();
        var data =  $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://dev.cts.cl/app/visitors/userinfo/",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf);
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: "json"
        })
        
        console.log("000-o");

        event.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

I'm not happy I had to turn off form security, and I hope I'll find out how to do this right. I'd also like to return responses from my controller class but haven't figured out that either (from what I've found online I get an error 500).

Comment: TIPS: You have created a `newEmptyEntity` to variable `visitor`, and send to the view file,  .. Then you can use `<?= $this->Form->create($visitor) ?>` to Auto validate form. (Ex: required/Max-min length, type, etc as per your DB tables)